# Problems with MVC 3 dropdownlist in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, webgrid

I'm trying to display a dropdown list in a webgrid, but I can't get it to work :(

I'm getting the following error: (on last column in the view)

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string,
>   System.Func, string, bool)' has some invalid
>   arguments \Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\foo\bar\Views\Admin\ManageRoles.cshtml

Hope you can make sense of the code.

**Model**:

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Role { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles1 { get; set; } 

        public string Email { get; set; }        
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult ManageRoles()
            {
                var users = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(x => new UserViewModel
                {
                    Name = x.UserName,
                    Email = x.Email,
                    Roles1 = RolesList,
                    Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(x.UserName).FirstOrDefault()
                });
                ViewBag.Roles = users;
                return View(users);
            }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList
            {
                get
                {
                    return Roles.GetAllRoles()
                        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = x,
                            Text = x
                        })
                        .ToList();
                }
            }
```

**View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManageRoles";
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, defaultSort: "Name");
}

<h2>ManageRoles</h2>

    @grid.GetHtml(
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Name"),
            grid.Column("Email"),
            grid.Column("ListItemId", "Role", format: ((item) => Html.DropDownListFor(item.Role, item.Roles1)))
        )
    )
```